# Is there a size limit for choices dict as Enum in Django model column?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to implement a article model that has a category field such as (Economics,Civil Engineering,Philosophy) and I want the disciplines as detailed as possible, so the choices dict would be very large. Is there a size limit on this filed that I need to worry about?

Is there a better way of doing this?

To clarify things a little. 
Suppose I have the following model.
Is there a size limit on YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES dict?

```
from django.db import model

class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES, default=FRESHMAN)
    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in (self.JUNIOR, self.SENIOR)
```

Comment: Not really. If it gets too big you might run out of memory, and it will become bewildering for the user, but there aren't any technical limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Django docs have not defined an upper limit for the number of choices  in Model Field Choices documentation.**

So, you can go ahead and define your detailed choices, it should not be a problem. Only issue could be running out of memory as [jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) also pointed if the `choices` tuple/list is huge.

It would be better if you put your `choices` in a separate file `choices.py` and import it into your `models.py` so that the models does not look cluttered and dirty.